# Convert 5V to 3.3V without logic level converter

Tags: spi, logic-level, tft

I've got a 2.2 SPI monitor (QVGA TFT monitor & SD Card), but I am using Arduino UNO board. All pins are 5V. How can I use a resistor to communicate between TFT, SD and UNO?

I have lots of different Ohm resistors, and have 3 Logic Level Converter (non bi-direction).

[image: 2 Channels LLC]
[image]

I try the LLC connect to TFT, but no luck, it just has the backlight ON, nothing I can see.

Thanks TJ, I had wired with this circuit, but the voltage seems not enough 3V. Am I something go wrong?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJfkKz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also, I have try to change R1 to 330 ohm & R2 to 680 ohm. Seems also cannot convert to 3V / 3.3V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple voltage divider to make 3,3V from 5V. 3,3v is high enough for the arduino to detect it as a high input.

Take for r2 470 ohm and for r1 220 ohm.

Comment: Thx, but I use 100 ohm for R1, 200 ohm for R2. Thanks